# Controls missing using UIAutomation, but not with Inspect.exe

Tags: c#, ui-automation

I'm retrieving controls (children of a toolstrip), but the list isn't complete throught the code, while Inspect.exe is retrieving the full list.

The only useful information is that the "Cancel" and "Validate" ToolStripButtons are instantiated dynamically (programmatically).

I did not found any explanation.
Has someone something about this ?

Thanks & Greetings

On these screenshots, the common parent is toolStrip1 (toolbar), the code shows all children displayed in Inspect.exe but the last three ("", "Cancel", and "Validate").

[image: In Inspect.exe]
[image: In Code]
[image: Visual Studio Watch]

Comment: I guess Grip and Separators are NOT being returned as controls. Total 18 Elements - 1 Grip - 3 Separators = 14 Elements.

Comment: Thanks @sallushan for the answer.
Grip and Separators was retrieved, I just got three buttons not found in the list, where the one I wanted was, solved as below.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

The problem was I used the UIAutomation library from Visual Studio Enterprise 2017, but that its version is a bit obsolete.
So I decided to use an "extended version" (according to me) called **UIAComWrapper** which has extended attributes for AutomationElement and allows to retrieve the complete list of controls.

**So UIAComWrapper do the job.**

This answer will be marked as Solution *asap*.